# Change CSS with AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs

I have an element of a web application whose class is connected to a CSS with the following values:

```
.map-darken img.leaflet-tile {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(0.99) contrast(1) saturate(465%) hue-rotate(343deg);
  filter: brightness(0.99) contrast(1) saturate(465%) hue-rotate(343deg);
}
```

I need to know how I can change the values of brightness, contrast, saturate and hue-rotate dynamically with AngularJS indicating the values in some text fields like the ones shown in the image:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYaDQ.png)

Or failing that, knowing how to indicate in the ng-style directive the specific classes you want the style to affect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39446602/how-to-change-a-css-property-dynamically-in-angularjs  ?

Comment: @GMR516 but there also changes the class of the element and the background color is applied to the whole new class, I need to only change those elements in the class indicated by the css.

Comment: Ah. Perhaps you can make each value a different class and remake those classes every time?